# HttpErrorResponse 200 after successfull POST in Angular

Tags: angular, upload

I upload one file from Angular 5.xx to Jersey 1.xx via FormData.

The data gets received and saved successfully on my server app directory, but Browser says this line from the picture (Chrome and Firefox).

When I upload it via HTML only like so:

```
  Choose file to upload<br>
    <form action="http://localhost:8181/BackendMaven" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="input" id="filename" type="file" /><br><br>
        <button name="submit" type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

it won't show up.

Here is the angular FromData Code:

```
@ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput; 
submitFile(): void{ 
    console.log("submitFIle called!!!");
    let fi = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
     let fileToUpload = fi.files[0];
     let formData = new FormData();//empty formdata
     formData.append("input", fileToUpload);
     console.log(formData.get("input"));
     this.http.post(this.URI_UPLOAD,formData).subscribe();}
```

And Server Side (im using tomcat)

```
public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("input") InputStream uploadedInputStream, @FormDataParam("input") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
  ...
        return Response.status(200).entity("Successfully uploaded to location: " + FileFactory.getFilePath(uploadedFileLocation)).build();

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: 200 ok is a perfect response for Post untill and unless you send a response from the server back to angualr for post

Comment: Changed from Respsonse to void to see if error disappears, and it did. But what approach is correct for Post. I read I should return 302 but that resulted in the same error message linked in the image.

Comment: You should just send a flat 200 back from the server without a message.

Comment: return Response.status(200).build(); ist still responsing with this error from above.

Comment: Not familiar with tomcat, can you just return Response.status(200);?

Comment: build() builds the Response Object. As mentioned it works using html formdata, only angulars approach causes this error...

Answer (score 37):

Try to actually send a JSON response, or tell angular to expect something different. If you're using [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient), it will by default expect JSON.

Something like this:

```
this.http.post(url, body, { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 3):

i have the same error

you must change the response from json to text

datatype by default is JSON

this way make new error in observable and the solution of this case

```
this.http.post(url, body, { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe();
```

this way make new error because  observable and the solution in this case

> ERROR in src/app/myS.service.ts(24,54): error TS2322: Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'

you must use this pattern to solution it

```
    returnObservable(): Observable<any> {
  const requestOptions: Object = {
    /* other options here */
    responseType: 'text'
  }
  return this.http.get<any>(url, body, requestOptions);
}
```