# How to ping IP Address in Angular 7

Tags: angular, ping, angular7

I want to ping IP Address to get response either it is alive or not by getting some sort of response or hack.

```js
ping() {
    return this.http.get('http://192.168.2.101')
}

this.deviceService.ping().subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result)
})
```

but I am getting this error.

[image: error in console]

Comment: Use server to ping for you and use response of it in angular

Comment: This app I am building is just an angular with no server side. Is it not possible with angular?

Comment: You Angular app can work over two protocols: HTTP and WebSocket. Ping works over ICMP protocol that is not supported by browser. As an option your Anglar app may ask server side about sending pings and return result back to the Angular.

Comment: Its a cross origin issue. For a local development you can use Allow CROS plugin.

Comment: Actually I need to ping router connected devices (local network devices) so how it can be achieved?

Comment: @PraveenGupta can you post an answer with proper solution please?

Comment: See your issue is that you are pinging from the browser and most modern browser blocks cross origin requests unless the server or your device allows it. I have not used Allow CROS Plugin but I doubt it will work even if it is used. This is more of a browser blocking the issue . If you have the option to make changes to router software to allow COR headers it will be great. Else you will have to send the request to your app server and then make a request to the router for specific needs. That's the right way if dealing with use cases where you can't add a CORS header.

Comment: The best and cleanest way to do this is to implement a small node-server which pings the requested ip-address and returns if it can be pinged or not. And you call the server from angular. If you want that i can maybe create a little prototype.

Comment: but that's not the requirement. Only client app needs to do that without any server.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example if anyone **has** to do it from the client, one use case could be if you **must** know wether the client is online or not, for example in a Ionic app.

Please see full working example in [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-ping?file=src%2Fapp%2Fconnection.service.ts) (You can check the console also to see each ping attempt).

```js
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { first } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
...

private source = interval(3000);
...

this.source.subscribe(() => {
  this._http.get('https://www.google.com', { observe: 'response' })
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe(resp => {
    if (resp.status === 200 ) {
      console.log(true)
    } else {
      console.log(false)
    }
  }, err => console.log(err));
});
```

`first()` is important to take only first value, since interval will make new request this is how we avoid memory leaks.

`{ observe: 'response' }` is how we tell `httpClient` to return the full http object instead of the body alone, this way we can acces status code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, ll test it soon :)

Comment: Thanks hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks. It works also for me. But I receive a "HttpErrorResponse" with status 200. Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe your response format is not right? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47378340/httperrorresponse-200-after-successfull-post-in-angular

Comment: @WasiF hi! just curious as of what was your approach in the end. Could help feature readers since this answer didn't help.