# Is it possible to ping local adresses in Angular ? (like in terminal)

Tags: angular, typescript, ping

I'm searching for a method to ping local devices on my network, like if I use de ping command in my terminal, to ping my router or any other devices connected.
I already found way to ping server like google.com but it seems it's not working on local address.
Is that possible or not ?
Here is my typescript code:

```
private source = interval(3000);

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

...


getStatutDevice(ip: string){

    //IP Value look like "192.168.1.20" for example

    this.source.subscribe(() => {
      this._http.get(ip, { observe: 'response' })
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(resp => {
          if (resp.status === 200 ) {
            console.log(true);
          } else {
            console.log(false);
          }
        }, err => console.log(err));
    });
}
```

I got this error in the console:

***zone-evergreen.js:2863 GET http://localhost:4200/192.168.1.20 404 (Not Found)***

If I put "https://" before the ip address, I got:

***GET https://192.168.1.20/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED***

I don't know what this means to find a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ping IP addresses using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954741/how-to-ping-ip-addresses-using-javascript)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53826264/how-to-ping-ip-address-in-angular-7?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

There is this typescript [utility](https://github.com/justintaddei/tcp-ping). It gives the ability to send a tcp ping.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer ! I'll check that !

Comment: It seems that this typescript utility only work on node.js, but not in browser. I saw that it was impossible to ping local address like that from a browser, for securities reason. i don't knwo if it's true, if there is alternative. I wanted to ping my local devices from my angular application

Comment: You can create a serverside service and call it with a http request from your angular application. Probably, this is simpler thant trying to ping directly from browser.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do an ICMP Ping ("like in the terminal") in a browser. Any attempt to do it will either be tcp or http get requests.

Comment: Thank you for your quick anwser! Http get can ping like that ?

Comment: You can do http GETs, but if there's no webserver at the other end you won't get a reponse. A router has a webserver on the LAN side usually so that should work. But a lot of other devices such as phones or desktops, usually won't have a webserver running, so you will always get a negative response.