# Angular 8 SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse httpPost

Tags: angular, http

Iam trying to send form Data from my Service to the Server but i get an error Respons everytime also the File is Uploaded Properly: How can i avoid the error msg

Upload.Service.ts:

```
  uploadFile(id: number) {
    let success = false;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization' : ' Bearer ' + this.authService.authToken()
    });
    const options = {
      headers: headers
    };
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.files[id]);
    this.http.post(URL, formData, options).toPromise().then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        success = true;
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        success = false;
     });
     return success;
 }
```

Error:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:5000/api/upload", ok: false, …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:5000/api/upload"
ok: false
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:5000/api/upload"
error:
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:19729:51) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:6246:31) at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:81825:33) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:6245:60) at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:6023:47) at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:6320:34) at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7458:14) at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7495:21)
text: "BlaBla - Kopie.sds"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
constructor: class HttpErrorResponse
__proto__: Object
```

Can somebody Help with that please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make sure your backend server returns a `JSON`formatted output as the response of file upload api.
or you may overwrite the default `responseType` to the format you are working with.
or you may read the full response without any preprocessing
https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48073486/6543507

Answer (score 0):

I believe that normally Angular will know have to handle **FormData**, and accept the right **responseType** if the server returns a JSON.

I would suggest you to create an interceptor to append the Authentication Header and not override the headers with the options as in your case.

[@ryanchenkie|angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8)